# Guard not catching the correct data

Tags: erlang, guard

[image: Code and Debug Info]

So here's my code, I don't understand why my second guard isn't catching the data. As you can see on the debugger the data is the same. Unless I'm blind I cannot see the problem

Comment: Instead of linking to some other page, edit your question and add an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You probably already bound `Data` to another value prior to the `receive`, and that value is different from what's being received.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Data` is bound to the value `"hey\n"`, but the `{tcp,S,_}` tuple you're receiving has a 3rd element of `"HEY\n"`, which does not equal the value of `Data`. Change that `receive` clause to:

```
{tcp,S,Data2} ->
```

or some other unbound variable name — anything other than `Data` — and all will be well.

Comment: You were right and I was indeed blind, I also had to change S because it was bound too. Thanks for the help! :)